# bash autocomplete not working, does not 'complete'

Tags: bash, ubuntu, autocomplete

I my `bashrc.` I have a bash completion for the command `scp` implemented as follows

```
function _scp_complete
{
  COMPREPLY=""
  COMPREPLY+=( $(cat ~/.ssh_complete ) )
  COMPREPLY+=( $( find . ! -name . -prune -type f ) )
}
complete -F _scp_complete scp
```

The idea is that when pressing `scp [tab]` I see all files in the current directory and the words listed in the text file `~/.ssh_complete`. Let's assume this file contain the following entries:

```
alex@192.0.0.1
alex@192.0.0.2
```

The desired behavior is as follows: I type `scp alex@ [tab]` and tab completion'completes' the command to `scp alex@192.0.0.` automatically, because there are only two possible arguments starting with `alex@` (assuming there is no file named similar to that in the currect working directory.).

The behavior I get with the current implementation is as follows: I type `scp alex@ [tab]` and the tab completion does not complete anything, but lists every possible argument below the command.

How can I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
_foo() 
{
  local cur
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  opts=""
  while read line           
  do           
    opts+=" $line"
  done < ~/.ssh_complete
  opts+=" "
  opts+=$(find . ! -name . -prune -type f)
  case "$cur" in
    *)
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '$opts' -- $cur ) );;
  esac

  return 0
}

complete -F _foo scp
```

Comment: @Alex: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark.